# Using SendGrid with script task in SSIS packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis, sendgrid

By using VS 2017, I created a SSIS package and then tried to utilize SendGrid with Script Task component but I kept have error messages. Error message is "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." The following is my code and please help me look at what's wrong with it. Thank you.

```
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    static EmailAddress yao = new EmailAddress("user@sample.com", "User Sample");
    static string template_id = "SendGridTemplateID";
    static string _api_key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridKey"];
    public void Main()
    {

        SendEmail().Wait();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    static async Task SendEmail()
    {

        var client = new SendGridClient(_api_key);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage();
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("Sample@user.com", "Sample User"));
        msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("Sample@user.com", "Sample User"));

        msg.SetTemplateData(GoogleLinkReport);
        msg.SetTemplateId(template_id);

        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

    }
    static GoogleLink GoogleLinkReport = new GoogleLink
    {
        header = "This is google link",
        text = "Please click the button to open the link for google",
        subject = "GoogleLink",
        c2a_link = "https://www.google.com",
        c2a_button = "Google Link"
    };
    public class GoogleLink
    {
        public string header;
        public string text;
        public string subject;
        public string c2a_link;
        public string c2a_button;
    }

}
```

Comment: @billinkc sorry I just edited my question and included the error message.

Comment: That's the SSIS error. Put in a break point and step through it.

Comment: Are you using a 3rd-party component like cdata sendgrid?

Comment: @wp78de Actually I don't use 3rd-party component. Is it necessary to use it?

Comment: No, but many do I believe.